# Wordpress WP Query display all posts with specific tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure this should be simple, but doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
$query1 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1'); // getting all posts works fine
$query1 = new WP_Query('tag=slug'); // getting the slug works fine
```

but putting the 2 together ain't happening. I've tried:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1', 'tag=slug');
```

and...

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag' => 'slug' ) );
```

No luck.

Comment: Have you tried `$query1 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&tag=slug');`?

Comment: Also, don't forget to add `wp_reset_query()` after traversing `$query1` to restore the original `WP_Query` and `$post`.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Not needed here. He is creating a new query object not altering the global $wp_query. [Look it up.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: @iambriansreed I thought WP_Query used the singleton pattern, IDK where I made this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1&tag=cooking' );
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $query->posts, 1 ) . '</pre>'; // this line is for debugging purposes only.
```

You are missing the ampersand '&'.

See:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Comment: Yep. That's the one. Thanks very much!

Comment: I am using a few of these, and `wp_reset_postdata();` after each. Does that make sense?